# How can I disable friend notifications on Xbox Live?

Tags: xbox-360

When a friend logs into Xbox Live, a notification pops up. This interrupts movies and games. Is there a way to disable the notifications?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Go to **Xbox Guide button** → **Preferences** → **Notifications** and edit the options.  You can also set your Xbox Guide online status to "Busy".

Comment: Why the hell is this listed under 'Personal Settings?' No wonder noone can find it… :/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this has changed. As of 11/8/13, it's now:

Xbox Guide button → Preferences → Notifications.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers left out a step, making it hard to figure out how to make changes. Here's a step-by-step list showing how you turn off the annoying notifications on Xbox 360:

1. Press XBox Guide button (the big button on the top center of the controller)
2. Navigate to the "Settings" tab (last one on the right)
3. Select "Preferences"
4. Select "Notifications"
5. Here's where you have the option of turning off all pop-up notifications by un-checking the box, or turning them off only when you're watching a video, and/or turning off the sound that plays when a notification pops up.